# What is the Usage of REM in Postbuild event

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am using `REM copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"  "C:\Data\Code\Test"`

but could not understand it's usage.

copy is doing just fine without REM. I am not able to see anything on output window .So why I need to use REM?

Comment: It is batch file comment, iow the line is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REM` stands for Remark and is a way to create comments in you Batch files.

Putting `REM` in front of a PostBuild event essentially turns it off, without having to remove the event. When you want to turn it back on you don't need to reconstruct it, you can just remove the `REM` in front of it.